# How to display muti-character constant in MSVS watch window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've got an int variable with the value assigned from a multi-character constant and the watch window show it to me as the number, is there a way to ask it to display the original value (maybe through a cast)?

i.e. I want to see

```
var    |      'abcd'
```

instead of

```
var    |      194345432231
```

(disclaimer: values are dummy values)

Comment: Have you tried just casting it to `char*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast (+ possibly [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/75w45ekt.aspx)) might be of some use, however the flexibility there is limited:

[image]